# iOS app backend where to start?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, sockets, networking

I need to make web server backend to help me send data from one iPhone to another and vice versa using mobile internet (3g, lte, ect.) and wi-fi too. I want to make app that send small data package to another device and in the same time gets similar data package from the device. I want to do this through Game Center, but since this is not acceptable for not a game apps, I decide to do this myself. First device know that another device want to connect with them (just a clarification).

I'm familiar with Objective-C, PHP/MySQL and web server administration(just a little). But, I never make such things as establish connection between devices and web server and data transfer between devices. I don't know where to start and what approach to choose. I'm searching for this but don't find answers for my concrete questions.

How can I establish connection between two devices? 
I must connect to web server first device (pull), then store some device identifier to database (DB) and then establish connection from server to second device (push) and provide first device identifier for accepting connection?

Or I must connect two devices to web server and give server info about their identifier and target device identifier then start to wait until server will get two pairs of such equals identifiers, then server will deliver data package from and to devices? How I can implement this in code(PHP)?

Or another thoughts, when two devices connect to server and server find two pairs of identifiers, server give the first device ip+port / socket and first device connect directly to second device, peer-to-peer. I know there are some troubles with p2p connection on 3g and other mobile internet.

This problem must be old as world, but I can't found some valuable info, may be I'm searching with wrong words. Please send me to right direction. I don't ask about implementation code, just some theory or resources.

Comment: You can use websocket for that for real time connections. If want to use DB use parse.com

Comment: Have a look at [Parse](http://parse.com).

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski looks like a popular place:), but I don't want to use DB, I don't know, I need to or not). Thanks for link.